# JPA Insert failed because of a zero value in my foreign key

Tags: java, jpa, orm, entity-relationship

I have the following multiplicities:
Order3d 1-----1..* DrawFile 1-----1..* Order3dLine

And I when I want to save the Order3d object I get a constraint violation because the DrawFile.id is put in my Order3dLine field and I got a **zero value** in my foreign key:

```
Hibernate: insert into order3d (delivery, demand_date, estimate_date, order_date, person_id, state) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) //OK
Hibernate: insert into draw (dimension, filename, format, hashname, hole, order3d_id, readable, size, slope, wall) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) //OK
Hibernate: insert into order3dline (duration, produced, quantity, color, draw_id, material) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
09:33:08,779 TRACE BasicBinder:84 - binding parameter [1] as [SMALLINT] - 0
09:33:08,780 TRACE BasicBinder:84 - binding parameter [2] as [SMALLINT] - 0
09:33:08,780 TRACE BasicBinder:84 - binding parameter [3] as [SMALLINT] - 2
09:33:08,781 TRACE BasicBinder:84 - binding parameter [4] as [INTEGER] - 0
09:33:08,781 TRACE BasicBinder:84 - binding parameter [5] as [INTEGER] - 0 //NOT OK
09:33:08,782 TRACE BasicBinder:84 - binding parameter [6] as [VARCHAR] - Something
```

My java classes are like this (I didn't put all attributes and methods because I guess it is not relevant):

```
@Entity
@Table (name="draw")
public class DrawFile implements Serializable {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="draw", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Order3dLine> line3ds=new HashSet<Order3dLine>(3);
}

@Entity
@Table (name="order3dline")
public class Order3dLine implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3993578603382571145L;

    @EmbeddedId
    private Order3dLine3dPK id=new Order3dLine3dPK();
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "draw_id", referencedColumnName="id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private DrawFile draw;
}

@Embeddable
public class Order3dLine3dPK implements Serializable {
    @Column(name="draw_id", columnDefinition="id", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private int drawId;
    private String material="";
    private int color;
}
```

Is an annotation missing?

Comment: You have to fill in your FK with a valid id

Answer (score 0):

A common source of mistakes for this is that you persist an order3d object but set the non-managed order3d object as a reference on the order3dLine object and as the referenced order3d object is not persisted, the order3dLine object gets a `NULL` key - try to persist the order3d object and re-set the reference on the order3dLine object with the managed order3d object before persisting the order3dLine object that the order3dLine object gets a reference to a JPA entity and not only a POJO.

Comment: My Order3d is fully filled and is stored in the session of my web application so myOrder is TANSCIENT then I call entityManager.persist(myOrder); to change myOrder state to MANAGED. But I got the problem described in my first post.

Comment: And the order3Line object has the managed order3d object referenced at the persist call?